# MySQL workbrench

Tags: java, mysql

Não continua, para 99%. Como faço para continuar a instalação ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Utilize o PHPMyAdmin, o Mysql Workbench não tem suporte a mais de uma década

Comment: Obrigado. Irei utilizar.